# How do you stop limes from drying out?

Tags: storage-method, lime

I bought a bag of limes and decided to leave them out on the table in a bowl after the last bag dried out in the fridge. They also dried out super-fast in a very few days. Should I keep them in a plastic bag? I don't live in a very dry climate. Thanks!

Comment: How do you intend to use the limes? If you're just juicing them, you could freeze the juice, for example.

Comment: (properly) dried limes are still usable - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dried_lime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cook's Illustrated recommends storing lemons in the fridge in a tightly sealed ziptop bag with the excess air removed. I would imagine that the same applies to limes. As I understand it, the idea is to prevent air circulation in order to reduce the rate of dehydration.

[Ref at thekitchn.com](http://www.thekitchn.com/the-best-way-to-keep-lemons-fresh-for-a-whole-month-tips-from-the-kitchn-144430)